Universal Property of Rounding
Let $I$ be the inclusion from the totally ordered set $\mathbb{Z}$ to the totally ordered set $\mathbb{R}$. Then $I$ has a left adjoint (ceiling) taking a real number to the smallest larger integer, and a right adjoint (floor) taking a real number to the largest smaller integer. More in-depth here.
Our intuition instead wants us to find a "middle ground" between the two with a "rounding" function sending a real number to the closest integer. But this seems to come from somewhere completely unrelated to the universal property that characterizes the floor and ceiling functors. Nevertheless would it be possible to characterize rounding via a universal property that generalizes to other contexts where a functor has both a right and a left adjoint?
(I would like to present my own take, but anything I've managed to come up with is artificial and unmotivated.)

There are two rounding functions and no obvious way of choosing between them (since there are reals that are equidistant to two integers and not closer to any other integer, such as $\frac{1}{2}$), so I don't see how you can expect to describe "the" rounding function as a universal property, given that there isn't just one. Rounding comes from the metric.

The two are isomorphic. There is also inclusions such as $3\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ that admit a notion of rounding with no ambiguity, so that doesn't seem crucial. I also observed that "rounding comes from the metric", but it is unclear how to generalize this to any functor with left and right adjoints.

"Isomorphic" in what context? What is your structure and what structure do your morphisms respect? How do you define your morphism of functions that turns "rounding up" to "rounding down"? I don't see you mentioning a metric before your comment, so I don't see how I (or anyone) was supposed to know that you had "also observed that 'rounding comes from the metric.'"

The issue of rounding up or down is fascinating, but only tangentially related to the question. I am not sure why one can infer that I expected the reader to understand that I had already considered that rounding comes from the metric, as I mentioned so in a reply and not in the main body of the question.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding mentions six rounding functions on the set of real numbers to the nearest integer. Which one do you take? And it does matter (unless you exclude those numbers with fractional part $0.5$).

Since we are talking about a concept using a metric space here, the appropriate generalization will probably talk about enriched categories (cf. https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metric+space#LawvereMetricSpace)

I was unaware that there was such a variety of sensible ways to round to the nearest integer. Unless I am underestimating the details, I believe I would be satisfied with a generalization of any of them.

We start by trying to generalize the notion of distance. In posets like what we are dealing with in the question, we know that the distance between $x$ and  $y$ is the number of objects $p$ such that $$x \leq p \wedge p \leq y$$This makes sense for finite posets, but it's not clear what it means for infinite posets. But we sidestep this issue entirely when we generalize from posets to categories.
This definition is motivated by the notion of turning $\leq$ into taking homsets and turning $\wedge$ into the cartesian product. For $X,Y$ objects of a category $\mathcal{C}$, define the (absolute) distance $$|X - Y| := \sum_{Z \in C}\mathcal{C}(X,Z) \times \mathcal{C}(Z, Y),$$the coproduct over $\mathcal{C}$ of the product of the relevant hom-sets.
Relativizing Distance
We now face the problem that the absolute distance between two objects of a poset doesn't actually give us what we want the distance to mean, but rather collapses it to a binary question. Thus, the notion of distance that we care about here is not for objects of the category, but rather with respect to functors.
For functors $F, G, H : \mathcal{C} \to {D}$, define the relative distance or $H$-valuation$$|F-G|_H := \sum_{X\in\mathcal{C}}|F(X)-H(X)|\times|H(X)-G(X)|.$$The images of such valuations form a category under inclusion. Define a mediator of $F, G : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ to be an initial object in their category of valuations. We now show that the mediator of floor and ceiling is a rounding functor, settling the question.
Proof
Let $I$ be the inclusion from $\mathbb{Z}^\leq$ to $\mathbb{R}^\leq$. We have an adjoint triple$$\lceil-\rceil \vdash I \vdash \lfloor-\rfloor$$from the ceiling functor $\lceil-\rceil$ to the floor functor $\lfloor-\rfloor$. For convenience, we now refer by these symbols to their composition with $I$, turning them into endofunctors.
Denote by $\lceil-\rfloor$ the functor $x:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}(x,\lfloor x \rfloor+\dfrac{1}{2})$. Our goal is to show that the set $$|{\lceil-\rceil}-{\lfloor-\rfloor}|_{\lceil-\rfloor} := \sum_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|\lceil x\rceil-\lceil x \rfloor||\lceil x \rfloor-\lfloor x \rfloor|$$is initial in the category of valuations of $(\lceil-\rceil, \lfloor-\rfloor)$.
The quotient $\mathbb{R}/I$ exists; denote the resulting projection functor by $\pi_I$. By composition, we obtain functors $$
\begin{align*}
\pi_I{\lceil-\rceil} &:= &0\mapsto \pi_I(0)\ \\
&&x:\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\} \mapsto \pi_I(1)\\
\pi_I{\lceil-\rfloor} &:= &x:\mathbb{R} \mapsto (\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})(x,\pi_I(\dfrac{1}{2}))\\
\pi_I{\lfloor-\rfloor} &:= 
&x:\mathbb{R}\backslash\{1\} \mapsto \pi_I(0)\\
&&1\mapsto \pi_I(1).\\
\end{align*}
$$By cases,$$
\begin{align*}
x \lt \dfrac{1}{2} &\implies \lceil x\rfloor = \lfloor x \rfloor\\
x = \dfrac{1}{2} &\implies |x-0| = |1-x|\\
x \gt \dfrac{1}{2} &\implies \lceil x\rfloor = \lceil x \rceil.\end{align*}
$$The outer cases imply that one of the factors in the valuation is the empty set, and so their product will be empty. The inner case implies that both factors are the same, and so their distance will be empty. Thus, the projection $\pi_I{\lceil-\rfloor}$ has as its image the empty set, which is initial under inclusion; and so is a mediator of $(\pi_I{\lceil-\rceil}, \pi_I{\lfloor-\rfloor})$.
As $\pi_I$${\lceil-\rfloor}$ is zero everywhere, the valuation of ${\lceil-\rfloor}$ is a coproduct of zeros, and so $\lceil-\rfloor$ is initial in the category of valuations of $(\lceil-\rceil, \lfloor-\rfloor)$.
